# How to get my next button code to work?

Tags: jquery

I am a beginner and have read a lot of the other questions in relation to this on here, but can not get them to apply to my code.  I am wanting my next button to click onto the next image in my lightbox photo gallery. I think that the steps should be as listed below:  However can not get the correct code to do this / or alter other peoples code to work for me.  If anyone has the time to explain this to me, it would be much appreciated.

```
         $($buttonNext).click(function(){
            $image.next().find("img") = $nextImage;
            $image.remove();
            $nextImage.show();
                    });


    <!doctype html>
    <html lang ="en"> 

    <head>
        <meta charset ="utf-8">
           <title>Photo Gallery</title>
               <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                   <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
                       <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
                           <link rel="stylesheet" href="base.css">
                               <link rel="stylesheet" href="nav.css">
    </head>

        <body>
            <header id="search-bar">
                <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search" value="search">
            </header>

                <div id="photo-container">
                    <ul id="imageGallery">
                        <li><a href="Photos/01.jpg"><img src="Photos/01.jpg" alt="photo of a dry hill" class="photo"></a></li>

                        <li><a href="Photos/02.jpg"><img src="Photos/02.jpg" alt="photo of a blue lake" class="photo"></a></li>

                        <li><a href="Photos/03.jpg"><img src="Photos/03.jpg" alt="photo of a shrub hill" class="photo"></a></li>

                        <li><a href="Photos/04.jpg"><img src="Photos/04.jpg" alt="photo of a snowcapped hill" class="photo"></a></li>

                        <li><a href="Photos/05.jpg"><img src="Photos/05.jpg" alt="photo of rocky red earth" class="photo"></a></li>

                        <li><a href="Photos/06.jpg"><img src="Photos/06.jpg" alt="photo of dry grassland area" class="photo"></a></li>

                        <li><a href="Photos/07.jpg"><img src="Photos/07.jpg" alt="photo of a green valley" class="photo"></a></li>

                        <li><a href="Photos/08.jpg"><img src="Photos/08.jpg" alt="photo of sandunes" class="photo"></a></li>

                         <li><a href="Photos/09.jpg"><img src="Photos/09.jpg" alt="photo of path with overlapping greenery" class="photo"></a></li>

                        <li><a href="Photos/10.jpg"><img src="Photos/10.jpg" alt="photo of an ocean at dusk" class="photo"></a></li>

                        <li><a href="Photos/11.jpg"><img src="Photos/11.jpg" alt="photo of a landscape through a gap in trees" class="photo"></a></li>

                         <li><a href="Photos/12.jpg"><img src="Photos/12.jpg" alt="photo of a lavendar field" class="photo"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!--closing photo-container-->

                    <div class = "arrows">
                        <div class = "previous">
                            Previous
                        </div><!--previous-->

                            <div class = "next">
                                Next
                            </div><!--closing next-->
                </div><!--closing arows div-->

            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
                <script src="lightbox.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
        JQuery Code


        var $overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
        var $image = $("<img>");
        var $caption = $("<p></p>");
        //button attemp
        var $buttonNext = $("<button> > </button>");
        var $buttonPrevious = $("<button> < </button>");


        //an image
        $overlay.append($image);

        //a caption to overlay
        $overlay.append($caption);

        //attemting to add buttons.  This worked now need to get them to scroll fowards and back.

        $overlay.append($buttonPrevious);
        $overlay.append($buttonNext);


        // add an overlay
        $("body").append($overlay);

        // capture the click event on a link to an image

        $("#imageGallery a").click(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
         var imageLocation = $(this).attr("href");
          console.log(imageLocation);

        //update the overlay with the image linked in the link
          $image.attr("src", imageLocation);

        // Show the overlay
          $overlay.show();
            $image.show();


        //Get child alt attribute and set caption

         var captionText = $(this).children("img").attr("alt");
          $caption.text(captionText);

        } );

        //When overlay is clicked

        $overlay.click(function() {
         $overlay.hide();
        $image.hide();
        });
```

Thank you for your time.

```
css



* {

    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

* {

    box-sizing: border-box;
}



/* mini header and navigation styles*/ 

.mini-header {
    background-color: #4484cE;
    height: 3.5em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1px;
    color: white;
     border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;

}

.mini-header h3 {
    text-align: left;  
    margin-left: .3em;
} 

.mini-header h3 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.mini-header h3 a:hover {
    color: #D9D9D9;
}


 .mini-header{
        position:relative;
    } 

 #tomatis-logo1, #facebook-logo1{
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    top: 8px;
    width: 2.5em; 
    height: 2.5em;
    border: 2.5px solid  #ffa31a;
    border-radius: 6px;

}

    #tomatis-logo1 {
        right: 25%;
    }

    #facebook-logo1 {
        right: 5%;
    }
/* main header and navigation styles*/ 

.main-header {
    background-color: white;
    height: 10em;
    margin-top: -1.25em; 
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
}

.main-header h1, h2, h4 {
    text-align: center;
}

.main-header h1 {
    padding-top: .5em;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #ccc;
}

.main-header h2, h4 {
    color: #ffa31a;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px darkgrey;

}

.main-header h2 { 
    margin-top: -.5em;
}

.main-header h4 { 
    margin-top: -1em;
}


.nav {
    display: flex;
}

.nav {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    max-width: 500px;
   list-style-type: none;    
}

.nav li a {

    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-left: -1.5em;
    margin-right: .5em;
    font-size: .8em;  
}

.nav li a:hover { 
    color: #D9D9D9;
}


/* colour styles*/ 

body {
    background-color: #D9D9D9;
}


/* main content styles*/ 

#large-cover-image {
    display: none;
}

#content-paragraph{
    display: none;
    font-style: italic;
    width: 20em;
    height: 20em;
}


#mobile-cover-image {

display: block;
margin:auto;
margin-top: 2em;
margin-bottom: .5em;
height: 40vh;
width: 70vw;
border: 4px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 6px;

}

/* card content styles*/ 

.card {

  margin: 30px;
  padding: 20px 40px 40px;
  max-width: 500px;
  text-align: left;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 6px;

}

#pam-image {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 6px; 
}

.main-content {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

footer {
    background-color: #4484cE;
    font-style: italic;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:30px; 
}

    footer p {
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}



    #menu .selected {
        width: 100%
        height: 20px;
    }


#willImage{

    height: 70%;
    width: 60%;
}
```

Comment: where did you declared you $nextImage?

Comment: like @NewbeeDev said. please provide the whole code.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time, I have added all html, css and JQuery code, but am not having any luck with the jquery code for the next button to function.  If you understand the steps needed for me to work through this task your input would be much appreciated.

Comment: `$image.next().find("img") = $nextImage;`  <-- not valid

Comment: Thank you, I will keep working on it.

Answer (score 0):

hope this is what you want, I only implemented the function for three images. change it as your need and refer the demo below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
</head>

<style type="text/css">

div#myimages{
 width: 400px;
 height: 400px;
 overflow: hidden;

}

div#myimages img{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}


</style>


<body>
<input type="button" name="" value="previous" id="pre">
<input type="button" name="" value="next" id="nxt">
 <div id="myimages">
  <img src="https://s.graphiq.com/sites/default/files/stories/t4/25_Longest-Living_Dogs_2867_2024.jpg" id="id0">
  <img src="http://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/1/590x/dog-650299.jpg" id="id1">
  <img src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-W__wiaHUjwI/Vt3Grd8df0I/AAAAAAAAA78/7xqUNj8ujtY/s1600/image02.png" id="id2">
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var idvalue = 0;
$("#pre, #nxt").click(function(){


 var the_clicked_id = $(this).attr('id');
 if (the_clicked_id == "pre") 
 {
  if(idvalue == 0 || idvalue <0)
  {
   idvalue =0;
  }
  else
  {
   idvalue = idvalue -1;
  }

 }
 else
 {
  if (idvalue == 2 || idvalue >2) 
  {
   idvalue = 2;
  }
  else
  {
   idvalue = idvalue + 1;
  }

 }


 var imageId = "#id"+idvalue;
 //alert(imageId);
 $(imageId).show();
 $("img").not(imageId).hide();

});


</script>




</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.